# How to iterate object[,] through entire rows

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

I get an excel on ftp everyday. I need to parse it and write to a DB2 table everyday. As u can understand; my excel has fixed columns with fixed order so I can iterate row by row instead of cell by cell to gain performance. The aim is to add every (`object[]`)**row** to datatable so the complexity could be O(n)

I know that jagged arrays can be iterated like this, not multidimensional arrays as I ask. However, maybe there can be tricks in my case. I have 1 method which I stuck and need your help..

1- I get the entire range from excel (cant use sheed.UsedRange, sheet is dirty somehow)

```
int usedRowCount = sheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Count;
string usedRange = string.Format("A1:DG{0}", usedRowCount);
object[,] rangeData = (System.Object[,])sheet.get_Range(usedRange).Cells.get_Value(missing);
```

2- Here I wanted to iterate with `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` to get entire row into a temporary object[] (as I have fixed data sequence of columns) but I see that BlockCopy requires the array type to be primitive, so this didn't work. But I feel the solution is close :)

So, any help, code, method (or explanation that this is not possible even in my case) is appreciated; thanks a lot.

Comment: You are reading/converting from excel. Nothing on the C# level is going to impact performance.

Comment: @HenkHolterman isn't it a performance gain to treat this Range objects as "Rows" instead of "cells" before adding into datatable ?

Comment: No. It's maybe 1% of the running time here, so even when you manage to double the speed you will have gained 0.5% overall.

Comment: I see, then lets go with traditional nested loops (:
Just curiosity; Is this because excel "Range" is working cell by cell in background even if I target whole row?

Comment: @stratovarius Check if it helps you http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d525b76-f5b6-4340-a899-c3c82570d2e1/is-there-a-twodimensional-arraycopy-method-?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to get the number of rows and columns, and then iterate through the rows.

```
int rows = array.GetLength(0)  -> Gets first dimension size

int columns = array.GetLength(1)  -> Gets second dimension size
```

This is the only option, since Array.Copy only works on arrays with the same dimensions. Buffer.BlockCopy isn't an option also since, as you stated below, it only works on primitives.

Comment: I know how to iterate through rows; the problem here is that I need to get the "whole" row into one object array, so I could set that object array into datatable.rows

Comment: I guess that is the only option you have.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong about `Buffer.BlockCopy`.
You can test this sample, it works.
`int[,] oResultTemp = { { 1, 2, 8 }, { 3, 4, 8 }, { 5, 6, 8 } };
int[] oResult = new int[3];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(oResultTemp, 0, oResult, 0, 3*sizeof(int));`

Comment: I am sorry, didn't read the documentation on MSDN correctly. It seems the Buffer.BlockCopy copies memory directly (that's why it only works on primitive types). I think you should do it your own, since there is no other solution for it.